# Has anyone successfully used watir-classic with the HTML 5 email element?

Tags: html, watir

I'm on IE11 and watir-classic 4.1.0 and I'm trying to interact with a new HTML 5 email element.  It's really just a text_field with a format checker to make sure the entered email address is in the correct format, however watir-classic can't find it as a text_field because its type is 'email'.

Has anyone found a way to work around this?  Is there a way that I could extend text_field to include email fields?

I'm not sure what the priorities are for new watir-classic development, but I can open a new issue to add HTML 5 element support.

Thanks!

-Tiffany

Comment: Do you know if the problem is IE11 specific? `browser.text_field` seems to work fine for me, but I only have access to IE9.

Comment: You should report it as a bug here: https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/issues Please make sure to provide relevant HTML and Ruby code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick responses!  It does look like a problem with IE10 and above.  I was able to get it to work in IE9 as well, but not in 10 or 11.  I'll open an issue in github.

Comment: I've opened issue #68 at github.com/watir/watir-classic/issues. Thanks again!

Comment: In case it helps someone else out, I've found a workaround.  I execute javascript to set the email address.  Here's the code:   browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('email_field_id').value='me@myemailaddress.com';")